# Count images in php and add class on ul

Tags: php, image, list, count

How can I add a certain class to the ul based on how many images there are?

So when there is 2 images the ul get `class"images one-photo"` and when there are 5 images the ul gets the class `class"images five-photo"` and so on...

**What I now have in code**:

```
<?php if( have_rows('blog_item') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('blog_item') ): the_row(); ?>

<ul class="images">
    <?php if( get_sub_field('photo-01') ): ?>
        <li><img src="https://www.website.com/<?php the_sub_field('photo-01'); ?>" alt="" /></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( get_sub_field('photo-02') ): ?>
        <li><img src="https://www.website.com/<?php the_sub_field('photo-02'); ?>" alt="" /></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( get_sub_field('photo-03') ): ?>
        <li><img src="https://www.website.com/<?php the_sub_field('photo-03'); ?>" alt="" /></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would come to mind:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$image_display = '';
for($i=1 ; $i <= 3; $i++){
  if( get_sub_field('photo-0'.$i) ):
      $count++; // count photos here
      $image_display .= '<li><img src="https://www.website.com/'.the_sub_field("photo-0".$i).'" alt="" /></li>';
  endif;
}
$class = '';
switch ($count) {
    case 1: $class = 'one-photo';break;
    case 2: $class = 'two-photo';break;
    case 3: $class = 'three-photo';break;
    case 4: $class = 'four-photo';break;
    case 5: $class = 'five-photo';break;
}

echo '<ul class="images '.$class.'">'. $image_display.'</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: I get no error but the ul stays empty and no classes gets added in the ul.

Comment: How high is your `$count` variable counting up to?

Comment: The max sub_field for the photo is 15 but not everytime every 15 fields are filled.

Comment: Did you extend the `switch`statement accordingly? In code above only 1 to 5 photos would work

Comment: Yup, made in the 'for' the 3 to 15 and i added 10 extra cases. Still the ul stays empty with li's.

Comment: Did your code work to display the photos? `echo $count;` to see what's going on...

Comment: My code in the start is working, yes. The echo displays '0'

Comment: I made a little mistake `if( get_sub_field('photo-0'.$i) ):` it should be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183661/discussion-between-edwin-krause-and-maanstraat).